# Drop page numbers in glossar

Tags: glossaries

In my thesis I have a lot of acronyms. the package acro doesn't work with my other packages so I am using a glossar. Does someone know how I can drop all the page numbers?

```
\addto\captionsngerman{% 
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}%
}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{wea}
{
    name=WEA,
    description={Windenergieanlage}
}

\newglossaryentry{hawt}
{
    name=HAWT,
    description={Horizontal Axis Wind Turbine}
}

\newglossaryentry{vawt}
{
    name=VAWT,
    description={Vertical Axis Wind Turbine}
}

\newglossaryentry{ip}
{
    name=PI,
    description={Performance Index}
}
```

This is a part of my document. I have many chapters. I insert every chapter by \input

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, bibtotoc, listof = totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left= 2.5cm,right = 2.5cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abb. }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{Abb. 10\quad}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Abb. 10\quad}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=iso-numeric,
            natbib = true,
            autolang = other,
            bibencoding=UTF8]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%%%%%%%%%Python%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}%https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  captionpos=b,
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
  language=c++,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=false,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  tabsize=3
}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\graphicspath{{img/}}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\input{98_Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}

\begin{document}


\raggedbottom
\input{01_Titelseite}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}


\onehalfspacing
\input{02_Sperrvermerk}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\newpage
\input{03_Abstract}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\newpage
\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\onehalfspacing

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


\input{03_Abstract}
\newpage
\listoffigures %Abbildungsverzeichnis
\newpage
\listoftables  %Tabellenverzeichnis
\newpage
\printglossaries


\newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\input{04_Einleitung}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, add a minimal example with code from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` or it is impossible to guess how you're defining the glossary.

Comment: I added a part of my document. Does this help or do you need to know which packages I am using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: I guess you should try the option `nonumberlist` in your package call of `glossaries`.